# passing a temporary lambda by const std::function reference should fail but seems to work

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference

This is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class thing
{
public:
    void register_fn(const std::function<void()> &fn)
    {
        m_fn = fn;
    }
    void run()
    {
        m_fn();
    }
    std::function<void()> m_fn;
};

int main() {

    // Create a thing object
    thing t;

    // In a limited scope
    {
        // Local lambda
        auto afn = []{std::cout << "hi\n";};
        // Store the lamda by reference
        t.register_fn(afn);
    }

    // Run the stored lambda (which should be destroyed - therefore dangling reference??)
    t.run();

    // Take a copy
    thing t2 = t;
    t2.run();

    return 0;
}
```

see it running here: https://godbolt.org/z/6qW3ro

So, I have a class that stores a temporary lambda passed by reference. The lamda `afn`'s scope is limited so that once it is passed to the register function it goes out of scope. Then outside of this scope I call the `run` function which should be running the (dangling?) reference to the lambda.

This has been working, but recently looking back at my code I have a doubt. Since the lambda is temporary (done here by limiting the scope of my lambda object `afn`) - this should not work... I can't quite get my head around why it is working - unless by luck and this is undefined behaviour?

Or... what have I mis-understood here? - because that is probably the most likely explanation!

Comment: oooh... hang on - I think I have just confused myself - I am passing by reference, but I am then taking a *copy* when I store it.... better just wait for you guys to confirm this! :o

Comment: Yes, it's copied when `m_fn = fn;`.

Comment: @songyuanyao phew - thanks :)  i'll close the question, but I have a query with Scheff...

Comment: @songyuanyao oh, no I dont :) - closing - or you can post your update as an answer - though I don't think this is now a useful question...

Comment: Please, forget what you probably want to ask. I didn't read carefully enough... (and realized when I intended to illustrate in CompilerExplorer). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff haha thats cool thanks! - had me confused for a sec  : ))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I was just confused...

Comment: FYI: I overlooked that the lambda is not itself the `std::function` but is wrapped into an instance of the latter. The `std::function` instance has indeed a restricted life-time...

Comment: @Scheff thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works principally because you make a copy of the function object.  In

```
void register_fn(const std::function<void()> &fn)
{
    m_fn = fn;
}
```

you assign `fn` to `m_fn` which makes a copy and and even though `fn` is a reference to the local lambda, making a copy means `m_fn` does not refer to `fn`, but will get a copy of the function `fn` has stored in it.  This means there is no dangling reference and your code has well defined behavior.

This would be different if the lambda captured a local object by reference, as that capture would become invalid after you leave the scope where the lambda was declared.

Comment: As an aside, `void register_fn(std::function<void()> fn) noexcept { m_fn = std::move(fn); }` would be better.

Comment: @Deduplicator ah std::function has a move c'tor - good point :)